# qual a diferença do this, do event.target e do event.currentTarget no escopo de um evento?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Qual a diferença entre o this, o event.target e o event.currentTarget no escopo de um evento?

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("meuId");
elem.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  console.log(this.id, event.target.id, event.currentTarget.id);
});
```

```html
<input id="meuId" type="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` é o próprio elemento que tem o evento associando, no seu caso, o elemento com "meuId".

`event.target` é o elemento quem disparou o evento. Imagine que dentro do elemento "meuId" existam outros elementos, que se clicados, disparam o evento do pai "meuId", `event.target` será esse elemento.

`event.currentTarget` é o mesmo que `this`. No caso de clicar em um elemento "filho" de "meuId", `event.target` será o elemento quem disparou o evento, e `event.currentTarget` será o "pai".

Pra ilustrar, veja o código abaixo:

```
<div class="pai" id="pai">
  <div class="filho" id="filho"></div>
</div>


$( ".pai" ).click(function(event) {
 // some code
});
```

Aqui, se clicar no div "pai" , `this`, `event.target` e `event.currentTarget` serão iguais, se clicarm no div "filho", `event.target` será o filho.

Veja um exemplo funcional aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/p08fh103/