# Pegar o id do audio tocado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar o ID do audio que o usuário da play, imaginei que algo assim funcionaria:

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
   $(this).attr('id');
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls id="musica1">
   <source src="https://65381g.ha.azioncdn.net/9/9/5/3/onlinepontocom-01-mais-uma-vez.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio controls id="musica2">
   <source src="https://65381g.ha.azioncdn.net/9/9/5/3/onlinepontocom-01-mais-uma-vez.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Ele até detecta o clique no play, mas não retorna o ID, existe algum forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É que aí vc tem que entender [qual a diferença do this, do event.target e do event.currentTarget no escopo de um evento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161469/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-do-this-do-event-target-e-do-event-currenttarget-no-escopo-de), se der um `console.log($(this))` verá que não é o retorno que estava esperando. Como pode ver no exemplo abaixo, se utilizar o parâmetro **`e`** mais a propriedade **target**, conseguirá obter o elemento que foi clicado em tela, pegando assim o valor do seu `id`:

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('id'))
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio controls id="musica1">
   <source src="https://65381g.ha.azioncdn.net/9/9/5/3/onlinepontocom-01-mais-uma-vez.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio controls id="musica2">
   <source src="https://65381g.ha.azioncdn.net/9/9/5/3/onlinepontocom-01-mais-uma-vez.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

**OBS:** No caso utilizando **jQuery**: `$(e.target).prop('id');`

Answer (score 0):

Faz dessa forma. Assim ele verifica o play em qualquer elemento de audio e te mostra a id atribuída ao elemento.

```
    $('audio').on('play', function(){
        var id_aud = $(this).attr("id");
    });
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls id="musica1">
   <source src="https://65381g.ha.azioncdn.net/9/9/5/3/onlinepontocom-01-mais-uma-vez.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio controls id="musica2">
   <source src="https://65381g.ha.azioncdn.net/9/9/5/3/onlinepontocom-01-mais-uma-vez.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```